# Выбор из ComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-xe2, edit

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе из комбобокса менялись и эдиты так, как они установлены в бд?
Например: DateOtpr.ItemIndex:=Marsh.ItemIndex;
Только combobox с edit.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `LookupCombobox`